# Wordpress Parent Theme is overridding Child theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to change the background image of the body of my wordpress child theme. When I preview the changes and use inspect element my child theme code shows however it is crossed out as it is overwritten by the code in the parent theme. I have narrowed the problem down to an inline php call in my header.php file to the custombody class in my parent style sheet. So I used the same class in the child theme and it still won't override the parent. I even tried to use a higher CSS specifity:

```
html body,
html body.custombody {
background-image:url('http://www.katekuhens.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/scribble_light_@2X.png') repeat #f3f3f3;
}
```

and the parent still overrides the child. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that at someplace else, either in your child css or the parent css, that custombody has a unique id? If that's the case, then no amount of class specificity will override the id https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/.